# Does GWT support classes in packages of external jars?

Tags: gwt, libgdx, box2d

I have [this](https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/src/b65fdab5b834315810b04343f91181d30a83a421/box2d/src/main/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DUtils.java?at=default) class:

```
package com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d;

/** placed in this package to have access to the protected {@code addr} fields */
public class Box2DUtils {

    /** @return {@link Body#addr} */
    public static long getAddr(Body body) {
        return body.addr;
    }

    // more methods...

}
```

The package `com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d` is in a dependency jar.
The class is part of my code though. Yes, I realize this is a hack.

Compiling this code results in this error:

```
Compiling module com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinition
   Validating units:
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/home/dermetfan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils/libgdx-utils-box2d/0.7.2/c4b052017a597e18b40c0dd7e42eff400d2f0731/libgdx-utils-box2d-0.7.2-sources.jar!/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DUtils.java'
         [ERROR] Line 24: addr cannot be resolved or is not a field
         [ERROR] Line 29: addr cannot be resolved or is not a field
         [ERROR] Line 34: addr cannot be resolved or is not a field
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

I suspect GWT has a problem with my class being part of a package from an external jar. Is that true? Any workarounds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GWT supports classes in packages of external jars.

However, if this is code that will run client side, i.e. that is being converted to javascript, then you need the source as well.

Comment: The source was available but the addr field really did not exist in the GWT backend. Thanks!